# Python mechanize BrowserStateError

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize

Is there any way to handle xml using python mechanize library.
I was using mechanize `.find_link()` method and it gave me the following error

```
>>> br.find_link(text="Help")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    br.find_link(text="Help")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 618, in find_link
    return self._filter_links(self._factory.links(), **kwds).next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 640, in _filter_links
    raise BrowserStateError("not viewing HTML")
BrowserStateError: not viewing HTML
>>>
```

where `br` is mechanize browser object..
From a little research it is because the page is non-HTML. Is there any bypass for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be extract HTML part from XML before you parse it to mechanize

Other solution would be removing the check in the actual [mechanize library](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize/_mechanize.py#L639)

Comment: Yes I had to do that, using BeautifulSoup

Comment: Yes, `soup=BeautifulSoup(file.html,'xml')` `mylink=soup.find('a','something')['href']`